# Google Groups public email

Tags: email, google-groups, google-groups-settings

I'm setting up a group in my company GSuite account. I want the Email-address of the group:

- to be public (i.e. Info@ ...) so anybody can send email to it
- I want all members to get the mail
- I want that any member can answer the mail
- and that by default the answer will be sent to the whole group and to the public email it came from.

I've succeeded with all but the last point. I can set it so the answer goes to the whle group, or to the external address, but I want both (why?: So all in the group know that that email has been taken care of). Is that possible?

Comment: Kindly follow only what's stated on the docs. Only do what is allowed. If it's not possible then it may not be supported. Try to check this [manage groups docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups).

Comment: @noogui Thanks for your comment. Maybe I wasn't clear, but I don't really care whether this is done via the API or the user interface. In fact, I might prefer the latter.

Comment: Does it fixed? OR still looking for the solution?

Comment: @Sachin G.: nope, not fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

As i could see the request you have made up is possible.

First 3 are very easy and basic requirement which is common in all big organizations. Make sure you have Paid Subscription to gsuite as under Legacy/Grandfathered/Free/Standard account the feature isn't included. For the last issue state the Solution is as follows

- Login to Gsuite Admin
- Click on Group on Dashboard
- Select the Group you would like add the role to
- Click on Access Settings
- Once the page is load click On Settings then Under submenu click Email options
- Find option called "Post replies" and select "To Entire Group"

After doing this when some other member of the group replies to an email it will send to entire group and to the sender is already under the reply algorithm.

Please let me know if need any other assistance. For better understandings i have attached an screenshot.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check it out on monday, and accept the answer if it works. I did see this option, but I think it is named confusingly. I thought then that the email will be sent to the whole group, but not to the original sender at all.

Comment: @EluciusFTW please test it. Should work. As the reply to sender is by default with the system or as you said you know how to do it. If don't know let me know will send screenshot and instruction for that as well.

Comment: I had to put his aside for a while but finall came around to testing it. Unfortunately the email reply is only going out to the group and not the public email address the message caem from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

2021 - now you can find this in admin.google.com > groups > "group name" > settings, there "Publish posts" tick "External". See https://support.google.com/a/thread/63946400/cannot-set-who-can-post-permissions-to-anyone-on-the-web-for-new-groups?hl=en&msgid=70496603 .